# Ошибка при компиляции C liboauth: hash.c:391:13: error: storage size of 'md_ctx' isn't known

Tags: c, windows, netbeans, oauth, cygwin

Windows 10 x64. В Netbeans создал новый C проект. Скачал liboauth 1.0.3 и подключил к проекту.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <oauth.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    const char *key             = "key";
    const char *secret          = "secret";
    const char *http_method     = "GET";
    const char *url         = "http://host.net/resource";

    char *req_url = NULL;

    req_url = oauth_sign_url2(url, NULL, OA_HMAC, http_method, key, secret, NULL, NULL);

    if (req_url) free(req_url);

    printf("Hello world!");
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**При компиляции выдаёт ошибку:**

> hash.c: In function 'oauth_sign_rsa_sha1':
>  hash.c:391:13: error:
>   storage size of 'md_ctx' isn't known

Функция oauth_sign_rsa_sha1 в hash.c:

```
char *oauth_sign_rsa_sha1 (const char *m, const char *k) {
    unsigned char *sig = NULL;
    unsigned char *passphrase = NULL;
    unsigned int len=0;
    EVP_MD_CTX md_ctx; // Здесь ошибка
```

Comment: Ищите, что такое `EVP_MD_CTX`. Возможно нужно добавить `struct` перед именем типа.

Comment: Уже делал поиск и в google и по репозиториям на github